# Fat fonts in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, fonts

In Kubuntu (both Precise and Oneiric) the font rendering is really different from Gnome.
The ubuntu font is not well displayed because it is always used the bold one instead of 'regular' resulting in a fat interface.

Is there a way to fix this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Fonts – KDE Control Module**.

Set *Use anti-aliasing* to *Enabled*, then press *Configure...* and try different *Hinting style* settings.
I use *Medium*.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I played with font settings in kde control module but also switching to slight or medium the situation doesn't improve.

Using the medium setting the fonts are no more bold but look weird (like in your screenshot), using instead slight (how it should be in GNOME) fonts looks bold.  

I believe this is related to this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+bug/744812
(it is marked as solved but it is still present!)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the Ubuntu font, which has not just Bold and Regular, but Bold, Medium and Light styles.

On your screenshot the font is bold because it's Medium style. Go to `System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Fonts` and select Light style:

[image]

Another solution - use another font. I insist you to try Droid fonts. For this install `ttf-droid` package.

Comment: wrong.. font is bold because qt4 is not able to use Regular weight and it uses Medium.
In kde settings I've used Regular weight but unfortunately this upstream bug makes fonts bold. Droid or other fonts are not a solution.. I want to use default stuff.

Comment: what precisely is wrong? i said the same thing - that kde is using Ubuntu Medium. I just didn't know the reason, which turned out to be a bug.

Comment: btw, i think in kde 4.8 it's solved